# Array iteration in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

So I have this array dynamically created:

```
array = [ "Name can't be blank", "Email can't be blank",
      "Email is invalid", "Password can't be blank",
      "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)",
      "Password confirmation can't be blank" ]
```

what I want is iterate through this array and if there is the value:

```
"Password can't be blank"
```

verify if there is the value:

```
"Password confirmation can't be blank"
```

and get rid of it.

So the returned array will be:

```
    array = [ "Name can't be blank", "Email can't be blank",
      "Email is invalid", "Password can't be blank",
      "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why bother? I'd rather you removed the "too short" warning if the password is blank.

Comment: You just wrote it: `array.delete("Password confirmation can't be blank") if array.include?("Password can't be blank")`

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you are able to do it. `include?` checks for `"Password can't be blank"`. `delete` deletes the item.

```
if array.include? "Password can't be blank"
  array.delete "Password confirmation can't be blank"
end
```